# Highchart - data points on one graph showing in the wrong place

Tags: highcharts

[image: Referencing this image]

I have two datasets (red, blue) that have data starting in 9/11 and one (green) with data starting in 2/13. The green one is starting in the same location as the others, but it should start in 2/13. How can I tell this dataset to do that? I'd rather not use 0's if there is a way around it.

Comment: can you give us the data you have used to plot the graph. a jsfiddle will do the job.

Comment: The preblem is with incorrect x data, could you supply how your series looks like ?

Comment: Hi guys- the data comes out of a database, here it is: http://pastie.org/private/0ltujlwqu8w7ee1z2jqtaa - i know that the line in question has less data, because the data for it just began being collected in 2/2013- I thought that the months and years would be matched up by Highchart so the data lined up. I guess not.

Answer (score 0):

You can put JavaScript's null value if you don't have any value. My English may not be that much good to explain but my example is clear. Also you can look at that page: http://www.highcharts.com/demo/area-missing/gray

```
             <script>
                $(function () {
                  $('.graph').highcharts({
                        chart: { type: 'line'},
                        plotOptions: { series: { connectNulls: true }},
                        xAxis: {categories: [2012,2011,2010,2009] },
                        yAxis: {title: { text: 'Example Fruit Consumption'}},
                        series: [
                            { name:'Apple', data:[null,null,20000,41000]},
                            { name:'Orange', data:[29458,29000,26892,23256]}
                                ]
                    });

                });
             </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define pointStart() http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.pointStart for serie.